# How to get current active link and anchor tag information ul li jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am working with jquery, i have 4 anchor tag inside ul li and i want whenever user search something then i want to know "current active link" so i can run my query according to selected "anchor tag",How can i do this ?
Here is my code

```
<ul class="categorisbtn" id="categorisbtn" name="categorisbtn">
              <li ><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="nav-link activelink" data-tagc="Company"><img src="images/inner-img/Company-Report.svg" alt="img" class="img-fluid"> Company Report</a></li>
              <li ><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="nav-link" data-tagc="StateR"><img src="images/inner-img/State-Report.svg" alt="img" class="img-fluid"> State Report</a></li>
              <li ><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="nav-link" data-tagc="BasinR"><img src="images/inner-img/Basin-Report.svg" alt="img" class="img-fluid"> Basin Report</a></li>
              <li ><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="nav-link" data-tagc="SectorR"><img src="images/inner-img/Sector-Report.svg" alt="img" class="img-fluid"> Sector Report</a></li>
            </ul>
```

And i tried with following code

```
$(document).on("keyup", "#search_param", function () {

              var interest = $('ul#categorisbtn').find('li.activelink').data('interest');
            alert(interest);
 });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the page load, on page head section you can add method to set active link -

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
  $('ul.categorisbtn li a').click(function(){
        // remove all classes
        $('li a').removeClass('activelink');
        // add class to the selected element
        $(this).addClass('activelink');
    });
});

</script>
```

**Then, on your search method**

```
$(document).on("keyup", "#search_param", function () {

  var interest = $('ul.categorisbtn').find('li>a.activelink').data('tagc');
  alert(interest);
 });
```